# Column name repetition in pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to read some data but the column names are repeatedly coming.

Here is a sample code:

```
for i in range(1, len(df_A2C), 1):
    A2C_TT= df_A2C.loc[(df_A2C['TO_ID'] == i)].sort_values('DURATION_H').head(1)
    if A2C_TT.size > 0:
        print (A2C_TT)
```

Output:

[image]

**I do not need column names. What should I do?**

Comment: Please, post a piece of your dataframe.

Comment: `print (A2C_TT.values)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply call the `values` method after `head`:

```
for i in range(1, len(df_A2C), 1):
    A2C_TT= df_A2C.loc[(df_A2C['TO_ID'] == i)].sort_values('DURATION_H').head(1).values
    if A2C_TT.size > 0:
        print (A2C_TT)
```

**EDIT:**

On a side note, I think that you may get away without iterating over your pandas dataframe.

I created an example dataframe to illustrate this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['COL_A'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 6]
df['COL_B'] = [100,200,666,200, 451, 42, 1664, 1665]
```

Below is your snippet modified for this dataframe:

```
for i in range(1, len(df), 1):
    A2C_TT= df.loc[(df['COL_A'] == i)].sort_values('COL_B').head(1)
    if A2C_TT.size > 0:
        print (A2C_TT)
```

I think that you may simply sort by `COL_A` (your `TO_ID`) and then by `COL_B` (your `DURATION_H`) and then group by `COL_A`, taking the *first* value in each group:

```
df.sort_values(['COL_A', 'COL_B'], ascending=[True,True]).groupby('COL_A').first()
```

Both snippets output the same dataframe:

```
    COL_B
COL_A   
1   42
2   200
3   666
4   200
5   451
6   1664
```

Comment: It worked but I am getting weird spaces `array([[37.        ,  1.        ,  0.45999444, 29.48446   ]])` Do you know this?

Comment: Not sure about the weird spaces, but I edited my question to describe an alternate processing strategy.